# How to customize search function in WordPress to not search by post content?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, search

I want to restrict WordPress default search function to not to search the content of the post. How did i do it?
I only want title, tags etc, but not the content of the posts to be searched.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have a look at [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Add some more information and tell us what you have tried, to make it more likely to get an answer.

Comment: take a look at this answer: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11822/how-to-limit-search-to-post-titles it could help